# touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled not worked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm tired to handle and solve issues related to multitouch. I'm using maximum 5 touches simultaneously but when two touches are down on two objects and I moved my fingers then that both touches fired `TouchPhase.Ended` event but not `TouchedPhase.Canceled`.

I want to fire `TouchPhase.Canceled` when my fingers are out of those objects.

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) { 
   hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchDown (hitObject); 
}

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) { 
   hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchExit (hitObject); 
}

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) { 
   hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchStay (hitObject); 
}

if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) { 
   print ("Touched canceled...."); 
   hitObject.GetComponent ().TouchExit (hitObject); 
}
```

Comment: "Ended" means the user lifted his finger, this is the regular event you should handle. "Cancelled" means the touch was forcefully interrupted (incoming SMS, gesture recognizer handling the touch) and is rarely sent.

Comment: But i m used Unity. In my Screen One Object When i touch down on that object that it is detected when i drag my fingure of the out side of that detected object at that time i want to handle that event. How can i do that ?

Comment: Let me clarify, firstly you touch an object. Then you drag your finger until its not touching that object anymore. And you want to handle an event when your finger exits that object on drag. Am I right?

Comment: Look,I have one object on my screen.I use raycast for detecting that object.in hitObject i m stored that hittedObject and when my fingure touchdown on that object then it works. if i touchup my fingure from that hitted object that is also worked.when my fingure is stayed on that object or i m move my fingure on that hitted object that is also worked. but when during moving my fingure if it is move outside that object at that time TouchPhase.Canceled event should be fired. but that can not worked . That is my issue. How can i solved it ?

Comment: That isn't what TouchPhase.Canceled does. The TouchPhase refers to the user's finger physically touching the screen, it has no idea what your objects are or whether or not your user is touching the object.

Comment: I want to stop dragging/swapping finger (not moving) on that hitted object how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your comment correctly

> Look,I have one object on my screen.I use raycast for detecting that object.in hitObject i m stored that hittedObject and when my fingure touchdown on that object then it works. if i touchup my fingure from that hitted object that is also worked.when my fingure is stayed on that object or i m move my fingure on that hitted object that is also worked. but when during moving my fingure if it is move outside that object at that time TouchPhase.Canceled event should be fired. but that can not worked . That is my issue. How can i solved it ?

and

> I want to stop dragging/swapping finger (not moving) on that hitted object how can i do?

you are going to have to restrict the swiping based on the touch position.

```
var realWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

if(realWorldPos.x < maximumXSwipePosition && realWorldPos.x > minimumXSwipePosition)
{
    //do the stuff you want to do
}
//otherwise, don't do it.
```